# Sequelize .save() on instance not working

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a model defined as below. I then try to run the code below it to update the isTeamLead property of a retrieved instance but I get the error `teamMember.save() is not a function`.

```
  const TeamMember = sequelize.define('teamMember', {
    userId: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    teamId: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    slotNumber: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    isTeamLead: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
  });


    Promise.all([db.models.TeamMember.findOne({ where: { $and: [{ userId: lead.id }, { teamId: id }] } })]).then((teamMember) => { teamMember.isTeamLead = true; teamMember.save() });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by making sure I was operating on the instance. Above I was operating on the array not the actual teamMember instance.

```
    Promise.all([db.models.TeamMember.findOne({ where: { $and: [{ userId: lead.id }, { teamId: id }] } })]).then((teamMember) => { teamMember[0].isTeamLead = true; teamMember[0].save() });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sequelize, you could do something like.
1) first find
2) if exist update

```
 const model = await Model.findById(id);

      if(!model) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Bad Request: Model not found' });
      }

      const updatedModel = await Model.update({
        key: value,
      )};
```